# Display JSON data in a ComboBox using java

Tags: java, json

I used the code below to retrieve json data and put it in a table. That worked. But I want to display the data in a combobox now. Right now, it is displaying the items in the dropdown in this format: ljava.lang.string @5c647e05
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
                        Hashtable response = parser.parse(reader);

                        java.util.List allResult = (java.util.List) response.get("AllResult");
                        System.out.println(allResult);
                        try {

                            String[][] data = new String[allResult.size()][4];
                            for (int i = 0; i < allResult.size(); i++) {

                                Object obj = allResult.get(i);
                                String result = (String) ((Hashtable) obj).get("Status");

                                String investorName = (String) ((Hashtable) obj).get("investorName");
                                if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                                        if (j == 0) {
                                            data[i][j] = investorName;                          }
                                                                            }

                                }
                            }

                            ComboBox investorNames = new ComboBox(data);
                            details.addComponent(investorNames);
                            System.out.println("Data here: " + data);

                            String[] columnNames = { "Seller's Name", "Stock Name", "Unit", "Price" };
                            TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, data, false);
                            Table table = new Table(model);
                            table.setScrollable(true);

                            details.addComponent(table);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to paste in **Combobox** only vector of invector names not whole array of arrays. As **Combobox** just invokes **toString()** on every array (row) of matrix, that's why you got *Ljava.lang.String@5c647e05* and not investor names. Something like this:

```
String[] comboData = new String[allResult.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < allResult.size(); i++){

    ...

    String investorName = (String) ((Hashtable) obj).get("investorName");

    comboData[i] = investorName

    ...

}

ComboBox investorNames = new ComboBox(comboData);
details.addComponent(investorNames);

....
```

Comment: @Grace please accept answer to close question, if you got what you want.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox expects an array of string but you are passing to it an array of array of strings.

So those ljava.lang.string @5c647e05 that you are seeing are the 'toString' representation of an array of strings.

You need to somehow (depending on what you need to do) flatten your 'data' so that it becomes an array of strings.